# Programmatically add a Fragment and set its Position

Tags: android

I got a FrameLayout and i programmatically draw something on it (FullScreen). That means every Element i added in `xml` file will be overlapped. So i figure i could add a `Fragment` like this :

```
    FrameLayout frameLayout =  (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
    CustomPlayView customPlayView = new CustomPlayView(getApplicationContext());
    frameLayout.addView(customPlayView);

    FragmentManager fragMan = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragMan.beginTransaction();

    Fragment myFrag = new PlayerInfoFragment();

    fragTrans.add(R.id.fragment,myFrag,"playerInfoFragment");
    fragTrans.commit();
```

But i couldnt figure out a way to put the Fragment to some certain position (in this case Center Bottom). And i also couldnt define a `Fragment` in `xml` file because it will be overlapped by the `CustomPlayview` i use.

Any idea ?

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to use the wrong solution for your real problem. You should have at least two separate `FrameLayout`s: one that you draw on and one that holds the `Fragment`. Alternatively, you can use a game framework such as LibGDX or Unit 3D that makes game development much easier.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice oh thanks i will try that !